# SQLite3 Query to list all tables in database only shows one table

Tags: php, sqlite

I need to be able to read all the tables in an SQLite database without knowing what the tables will be called. I'm working on the following example.db

*chinhook.db*

**Tables**

Album,
Artist,
Customer,
Employee,
Genre,
Invoice,
InvoiceLine,
MediaType,
Playlist,
PlaylistTrack,
Track.

Currently, I'm using the following...

```
<?php
    $db = new SQLite3('db/chinhook.db');
    $tablesquery = $db->query("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table';");
    $tables = $tablesquery->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC);

    foreach($tables as $name){
       echo $name.'<br />';
    }
?>
```

I can only ever seem to get the name of the first table. I can call data from the other tables no problem, but the sqlite_master table only contains one of the table names. Others online seem to report this method as successful. Any Ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does fetchArray() method do?

Comment: Standard SQLite3 method for fetching the results of a query and placing them into either a numerical or associative array (or both). Similarly to the way mysql_fetch_array does.

http://php.net/manual/en/sqlite3result.fetcharray.php

Comment: So, how many records it is supposed to fetch into a numerical or associative array?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
    $db = new SQLite3('db/chinhook.db');
    $tablesquery = $db->query("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table';");

    while ($table = $tablesquery->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC)) {
        echo $table['name'] . '<br />';
    }
?>
```

Comment: ->fetch doesn't seem to be a method in SQLite3
    Call to undefined method SQLite3Result::fetch()

Comment: Yeah, that was my bad. fetch() is defined in class SQLiteDatabase, but not in SQLite3 which you are using.

Answer (score 0):

**In PDO Method**

```
$db  = new PDO('sqlite:Northwind.db');

$sql = "SELECT  `name` FROM sqlite_master WHERE `type`='table'  ORDER BY name";
  $result = $db->query($sql);
      if($result){
        while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
          echo '<li>'.$row['name'].'</li>';
        }
    }


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

FYI, if you need to parse the returned sql

I implemented a sqlite table parser for it:

https://github.com/maghead/sqlite-parser

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
   $db = new SQLite3('db/chinhook.db');
   $tablesquery = $db->query("SELECT sql FROM sqlite_master WHERE name='foo'");
   $table = $tablesquery->fetchArray();
   echo '<pre>'.$table['sql'] . '</pre>';
   $db->close();
?>
```